# How to check a unit (C:) dirty bit using C#

Tags: c#, filesystems

I know it is possible to check the dirty bit status of a unit by running the command `fsutil dirty query c:` from an elevated prompt. On windows 10 it is also possible to know if C: dirty bit is set without the need of admin privileges simply going into the System and Maintenance page, if dirty bit is set there will be an advice telling it is necessary to reboot in order to repair a damage in the file sistem. How could the dirty bit status (of any unit or even only C:) be checked from a C# program?

Thanks in Advance to anyone will answer

Comment: You could run the `fsutil` process in-proc and reflect on the output it yields.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, AndreasHassing, I'd prefer to avoid doing this because fsutil output is language dependent, I'd have to parse its output differently according to system language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this information using a WMI query

```
var q = new ObjectQuery("Select * FROM Win32_Volume");
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(q))
using (var moc = searcher.Get())
{
    foreach (ManagementObject volume in moc)
    {
        String label = (String)volume["Label"];
        Boolean dirtyBitSet = (Boolean)(volume["DirtyBitSet"] ?? false);
        Console.WriteLine($"{label} => {dirtyBitSet}");
    }
}
```

You should add a reference to the `System.Management` assembly and also run your program using an elevated prompt

Comment: Many thanks! This solved my problem! A little improvement: I found that if there are unplugged volumes DirtyBitSet will be null in these volumes, causing the code to crash, I solved this writing "Boolean dirtyBitSet = (Boolean)(volume["DirtyBitSet"] ?? false);"